Remote access IPsec VPN tunnel connection between FortiGate firewall and native Windows VPN client fails to establish
Problem summary
I'm trying to setup a remote access IPsec IKEv2 VPN between a FortiGate firewall (FortiOS v7.2.8) and a native Windows VPN client with certificate based authentication.
I've went trough several tutorials but can't get the tunnel up and going. Also Fortinet customer support doesn't provide assistance if the configuration has never worked before.
Here's a simple network diagram of what I am trying to achieve :


Steps undertaken
These are the main steps of configuration I've followed so far. I give more details later.

Generate the server and user certificates and sign them using the certification authority

Configure the IPsec VPN tunnel

Configure the native Windows VPN client

Add a firewall policy on the firewall to allow traffic


But when trying to connect from the Windows client, I get the following error message :
Can't connect to TEST

IKE authentication credentials are unacceptable

Here you can see the logs that appear on the FortiGate right after a connection is attempted (I replaced the long strings of hexadecimal characters with dots) :
FortiGate # diagnose debug application ike -1
Debug messages will be on for 23 minutes.

FortiGate # diagnose debug application fnbamd -1
Debug messages will be on for 23 minutes.

FortiGate # diagnose debug enable

FortiGate # ike 0: comes <Windows VPN Client IP>:500-><Public FGT IP>:500,ifindex=23,vrf=0....
ike 0: IKEv2 exchange=SA_INIT id=ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000 len=544
ike 0: in AC35988........A5100000002
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: responder received SA_INIT msg
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: received notify type FRAGMENTATION_SUPPORTED
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: received notify type NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: received notify type NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: VID MS NT5 ISAKMPOAKLEY 1E2B516905991C7D7C96FCBFB587E46100000009
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: VID unknown (16): FB1DE3CDF341B7EA16B7E5BE0855F120
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: VID unknown (16): 26244D38EDDB61B3172A36E3D0CFB819
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: VID unknown (20): 01528BBBC00696121849AB9A1C5B2A5100000002
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: incoming proposal:
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: proposal id = 1:
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:   protocol = IKEv2:
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:      encapsulation = IKEv2/none
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:         type=ENCR, val=AES_CBC (key_len = 256)
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:         type=INTEGR, val=AUTH_HMAC_SHA2_256_128
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:         type=PRF, val=PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:         type=DH_GROUP, val=MODP2048.
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: matched proposal id 1
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: proposal id = 1:
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:   protocol = IKEv2:
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:      encapsulation = IKEv2/none
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:         type=ENCR, val=AES_CBC (key_len = 256)
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:         type=INTEGR, val=AUTH_HMAC_SHA2_256_128
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:         type=PRF, val=PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933:         type=DH_GROUP, val=MODP2048.
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: lifetime=86400
ike 0:ac35988f5bf4df3b/0000000000000000:6933: SA proposal chosen, matched gateway Remote user VPN
ike 0:Remote user VPN: created connection: 0xa221e60 23 <Public FGT IP>-><Windows VPN Client IP>:500.
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: processing notify type NAT_DETECTION_SOURCE_IP
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: processing NAT-D payload
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: NAT detected: PEER
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: process NAT-D
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: processing notify type NAT_DETECTION_DESTINATION_IP
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: processing NAT-D payload
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: NAT detected: PEER
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: process NAT-D
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: processing notify type FRAGMENTATION_SUPPORTED
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: responder preparing SA_INIT msg
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: create NAT-D hash local <Public FGT IP>/500 remote <Windows VPN Client IP>/500
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: out AC35988F........000402E
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: sent IKE msg (SA_INIT_RESPONSE): <Public FGT IP>:500-><Windows VPN Client IP>:500, len=424, vrf=0, id=ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: IKE SA ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8 SK_ei 32:606CFF2771758125FEAF9BE6D834251F6D124BF98E518A839FDA44BB4BE3D5BE
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: IKE SA ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8 SK_er 32:FE7A05A6F0CA2C63F07BCB4D30D56414FDE27992C064A63BE353131B97875A7D
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: IKE SA ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8 SK_ai 32:CD9FA84229595E357B8D1FDDF3C28F55564689EB3D089CD8485F248D345CD900
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: IKE SA ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8 SK_ar 32:DA67F9E25C7D75F19A8D49D5D59A1145FC82812AF7AA15932D246C4858876EB1
ike 0: comes <Windows VPN Client IP>:4500-><Public FGT IP>:4500,ifindex=23,vrf=0....
ike 0: IKEv2 exchange=AUTH id=ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8:00000001 len=580
ike 0: in AC35988F........FAEAA4D86C576
D
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: encrypted fragment 1 of 3 queued
ike 0: comes <Windows VPN Client IP>:4500-><Public FGT IP>:4500,ifindex=23,vrf=0....
ike 0: IKEv2 exchange=AUTH id=ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8:00000001 len=580
ike 0: in AC35988F5........B71873EA
4
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: encrypted fragment 2 of 3 queued
ike 0: comes <Windows VPN Client IP>:4500-><Public FGT IP>:4500,ifindex=23,vrf=0....
ike 0: IKEv2 exchange=AUTH id=ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8:00000001 len=420
ike 0: in AC35988F........FCB6C6
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: encrypted fragment 3 of 3 queued
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: dec AC35988F5B........600743D5
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: dec AC35988F5B........8D6C659
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: dec AC35988F........FFFFF
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: reassembled fragmented message
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: responder received AUTH msg
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: processing notify type MOBIKE_SUPPORTED
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: peer identifier IPV4_ADDR 192.168.3.68
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: re-validate gw ID
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: gw validation OK
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '0EAC826040562797E52513FC2AE10A539559E4A4'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'DDBCBD869C3F07ED40E31B08EFCEC4D188CD3B15'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '4A5C7522AA46BFA4089D39974EBDB4A360F7A01D'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '194587AE303611237B915DE583B741F760F273F3'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '5CB869FE8DEFC1ED6627EEB2120F721BB80A0E04'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '6A47A267C92E2F19688B9B86616695EDC12C1300'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '01F0334C1AA1D9EE5B7BA9DE43BC027D570933FB'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '8BD402B9E47A806F00D33ACBEEB32ECD0D11766A'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '83317E62854253D6D7783190EC919056E991B9E3'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '1602DA8D06CB43EE9A8A91A02D88D72BAA72AD07'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'CE9614AE0589A62D380FE473F7F26754DC79424D'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '88A95AEFC084FC1374416BB16332C2CF9259BB3B'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'F927B61B0A37F3C31AFA17EC2D461716129D0C0E'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '344F302D25693191EAF7735CABF5868D378240EC'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '3EDF290CC1F5CC732CEB3D24E17E52DABD27E2F0'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'F2052F9F9FD5A5933C9C6D7192CC457A16D3B7B6'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'A46D7AEFA0D823E59DF92AADCEF78C0B679E288F'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '7C32D485FD890A66B597CE86F4D526A92107E83E'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '68330E61358521592983A3C8D2D2E1406E7AB3C1'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '641DF8D50E2331C229B250CB32F56DF55C8E00FA'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'BF9EA8468328C1DBA829EE35CB8BA85F52F085D1'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'DAED6474149C143CABDD99A9BD5B284D8B3CC9D8'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '87E3BF322427C1405D2736C381E01D1A71D4A039'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '5E8C531822601D5671D66AA0CC64A0600743D5A8'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '8626CB1BC554B39FBD6BED637FB989A980F1F48A'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'ED0DC8D62CD31329D882FE2DC3FCC510D34DBB14'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'A8E3029670A68B57EBECEFCC294E91749AD49238'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'F79319EFDFC1F520FBAC85552CF2D28F5AB9CA0B'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '30A4E64FDE768AFCED5A9084283046792C291570'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'EFE7122486FBA28408E284B17A991D0E550572F9'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'C43028C5D3E3080C10448B2C77BA24539760BBF9'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'F816513CFD1B449F2E6B28A197221FB81F514E3C'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '9B10827A95032AB26B73C82F18C92ECAE568C208'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '69C427DB5969681847E252170AE0E57FAB9DEF0F'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '87DBD45FB0928D4E1DF81567E7F2ABAFD62B6775'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'C53021E4C84BD1A9E9DEE840BA6A169F77928F91'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '6E584E3375BD57F6D5421B1601C2D8C0F53A9F6E'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '4A810CDEF0C0900F1906423135A2A28DD344FD08'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'D52E13C1ABE349DAE8B49594EF7C3843606466BD'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'AB30D3AF4BD8F16B5869EE456929DA84B8739488'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '687421E97DCF229A80282DDF9720B6749B1668BC'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'A59DBF9015D9F1F5A8D8C01D14E6F1D8C4FE5717'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '07DAA7378C513B15AD74036A652E2E29206E21B7'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'E27F7BD877D5DF9E0A3F9EB4CB0E2EA9EFDB6977'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '7ADD9381569EE04137127BACAA16F0635BC37F3D'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '5FF3246C8F9124AF9B5F3EB0346AF42D5CA85DCC'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '70C72F89D8E3B1A6E5DECC3DFF5F2AA122052877'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'B181081A19A4C0941FFAE89528C124C99B34ACC7'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '210F2C89F7C4CD5D1B825E38D6C6593BA69375AE'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'BBC23E290BB328771DAD3EA24DBDF423BD06B03D'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'C89513680197280A2C55C3FCD390F53A053BC9FB'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq 'EEE59F1E2AA544C3CB2543A69A5BD46A25BCBB8E'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '4C75D4858062AAA9449C66151E6C5813053A9C72'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '174AB82B5FFB05677527AD495A4A5DC422CCEA4E'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: received peer certreq '4F9C7D21799CAD0ED8B90C579F1A0299E790F387'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: responder preparing EAP identity request
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: local cert, subject='|Q̬', issuer='!
'
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: splitting payload len=1712 into 2 fragments
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: enc 2500004F0900000030........6D336020102
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: enc 71CA6E2D7E38DA........605040302010C
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: remote port change 500 -> 4500
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: out AC35988F5BF4DF3BE7EE04207........BE40
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: sent IKE msg (AUTH_RESPONSE): <Public FGT IP>:4500-><Windows VPN Client IP>:4500, len=1124, vrf=0, id=ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8:00000001
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: out AC35988F5BF4DF3BE........91A580CF74
08BC80D6F
ike 0:Remote user VPN:6933: sent IKE msg (AUTH_RESPONSE): <Public FGT IP>:4500-><Windows VPN Client IP>:4500, len=740, vrf=0, id=ac35988f5bf4df3b/e7ee0420726427f8:00000001
ike shrank heap by 159744 bytes

FortiGate #

Details
Certificates
I followed the steps in this technical note from Fortinet KB showing how to generate and import certificates. I imported both the server and the CA certificate into the FortiGate.
FortiGate certificates view
I've also installed the client certificate on my machine.
Initially, I've also followed the steps in this guide to provide authentication using certificates for a specific user (tgerber) but I ended up selecting the accept Any peer ID option for the authentication section in the VPN configuration since it wasn't working anyway.
IPsec VPN Tunnel Configuration
Here's the configuration of the VPN tunnel on the FortiGate.
FortiGate # show vpn ipsec phase1-interface Remote\ user\ VPN
config vpn ipsec phase1-interface
    edit "Remote user VPN"
        set type dynamic
        set interface "x1"
        set ike-version 2
        set authmethod signature
        set peertype any
        set net-device disable
        set mode-cfg enable
        set proposal aes256-sha256
        set dpd on-idle
        set dhgrp 14
        set eap enable
        set eap-identity send-request
        set authusrgrp "VPN_Users_LAB"
        set certificate "server"
        set ipv4-start-ip 192.168.100.10
        set ipv4-end-ip 192.168.100.250
        set ipv4-split-include "local_network"
        set dpd-retryinterval 60
    next
end

FortiGate # show vpn ipsec phase2-interface Remote\ user\ VPN
config vpn ipsec phase2-interface
    edit "Remote user VPN"
        set phase1name "Remote user VPN"
        set proposal aes256-sha256
        set dhgrp 14
    next
end

FortiGate #

Please note that I've also run the following commands (as suggested in this post) while trying to fix the problem on my own.
config vpn ipsec phase1-interface
  edit Remote\ user\ VPN
    set eap enable
    set eap-identity send-request
    set authusrgrp VPN_Users_LAB
  next
end

Native Windows VPN Client Configuration
Here's the VPN configuration :



Field
Value




Connection name
TEST


Server name or address
FortiGate's public IP


VPN type
IKEv2


Type of sign-in info
Microsoft: EAP-AKA (I've also tested Certificate but without success)


Username (optional)
empty


Password (optional)
empty



However, I noticed that Windows uses obsolete encryption methods by default and to change them you have to run commands on the command line. So after searching a bit on the internet I ended up finding this command which I executed on the Windows client. This post helped me a lot.
Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration -ConnectionName "TEST" -AuthenticationTransformConstants SHA256128 -CipherTransformConstants AES256 -PfsGroup ECP384 -EncryptionMethod AES256 -IntegrityCheckMethod SHA256 -DHGroup ECP384

Firewall policy
Here's the only firewall policy I have related to the VPN.
FortiGate # show firewall policy 14
config firewall policy
    edit 14
        set name "Allow VPN Users"
        set uuid cc2c3754-4e4b-51ef-9e03-62773733f4b5
        set srcintf "Remote user VPN"
        set dstintf "port6"
        set action accept
        set srcaddr "all"
        set dstaddr "local_network"
        set schedule "always"
        set service "ALL"
        set logtraffic all
    next
end

FortiGate #


I don't really know what is preventing the VPN tunnel to work and what can be causing the issue. Thank you for help.

IKE certificate-based authentication is mutual. Have you made sure that the Fortigate's certificate is acceptable by the client, ie. imported the CA trust anchor?

Also, remember that host configuration is off-topic here. We cannot help with the Windows configuration.

I see (or imagine ;]) at least 3 problems with your configuration:

I believe that in certificates view your CA should be placed in a "Local CA Certificates" group, instead of "Remote". I believe the difference is that remote CA's lack private key. It's not likely being a reason of your problem, but may generate some headaches later.

In your config vpn ipsec phase2-interface you used Diffie-Hellman group 14 (set dhgrp 14), but later on the client you configured -DHGroup ECP384 (== DH group 20) - these have to be consistent on both client and server. Since the logs you provided clearly state (line 27): type=DH_GROUP, val=MODP2048., and modp2048 corresponds to DH group 14 I'm guessing you did it later? Also note, that with DH group 14 phase 1 completed successfully, and DH is used only for phase 1, meaning that after the change the amount of bugs in your config increased at least by 1 (and I suspect increase by two - more in the #3) :)

In any case - using ECP384 requires using elliptic curve certificates, and the link you provided does not guide to use those.

(not a problem - a feature ;]) Also note, that Fortigate provides its own VPN client called FortiClient.


To summarize: I'd reconfigure everything from scratch (including certificates - now adding CA to the "Local" CA's), move back to DH group 14 on your Windows client and start debugging process from installation of FortiClient and trying to use it instead of Windows native client. After you achieve success with FortiClient you can be sure your VPN "generally works", and diagnosing Windows client issues becomes separate process (separate from "does my VPN work at all" problem). Only then I'd play with changing certificates to EC.
Oh, one more insight: while creating your certs be very cautious where to use CA and where to use "server" cert/key.
When you'll get back to the state where phase 1 succeeds and phase 2 does not - try FortiClient and provide more logs, focused on phase 2.
